# 404 ERROR(file not found) when trying to log to an authentication system built in express and node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I am making a demo banking app which supports user sign up and sign in using express.js and node.js.
The api built accepts POST requests to `/signup` and `/authenticate` routes when called via Postman but the `/authenticate` route gives a 404 error when called through `$.ajax` on the login form.

This is the jQuery ajax request in index.html

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/authenticate',
        method: 'POST',
        data: cred,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(success){
          console.log(success);
        },
        error: function(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
      })
```

server.js this is the server file

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../public/index.html'));
});

app.use('/api', api(passport));
```

This is app.js where routing is done

```
'use strict';

var router = require('express').Router();

var config = require('../config'),
    allowOnly = require('../services/routesHelper').allowOnly,
    AuthController = require('../controllers/authController'),
    UserController = require('../controllers/userController'),
    AdminController = require('../controllers/adminController');

var APIRoutes = function(passport) {
    // POST Routes.
    router.post('/signup', AuthController.signUp);
    router.post('/authenticate', AuthController.authenticateUser);

    // GET Routes.
    router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), allowOnly(config.accessLevels.user, UserController.index));
    router.get('/admin', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), allowOnly(config.accessLevels.admin, AdminController.index));

    return router;
};

module.exports = APIRoutes;
```

The POST request to `/signup` works but `/authenticate` gives a 404 error when using Ajax. But `/authenticate` works as expected when using Postman.

This is the authController.js

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var config = require('../config'),
    db = require('../services/database'),
    User = require('../models/user');

// The authentication controller.
var AuthController = {};

// Register a user.
AuthController.signUp = function(req, res) {
    if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
        res.json({ message: 'Please provide a username and a password.' });
    } else {
        db.sync().then(function() {
            var newUser = {
                username: req.body.username,
                password: req.body.password
            };

            return User.create(newUser).then(function() {
                res.status(201).json({ message: 'Account created!' });
            });
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(403).json({ message: 'Username already exists!' });
        });
    }
}

// Authenticate a user.
AuthController.authenticateUser = function (req, res) {
  if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
    res.status(404).json({
      message: 'Username and password are needed!'
    });
  } else {
    var username = req.body.username,
      password = req.body.password,
      potentialUser = {
        where: {
          username: username
        }
      };

    User.findOne(potentialUser).then(function (user) {
      if (!user) {
        res.status(404).json({
          message: 'Authentication failed!'
        });
      } else {
        user.comparePasswords(password, function (error, isMatch) {
          if (isMatch && !error) {
            var token = jwt.sign({
                username: user.username
              },
              config.keys.secret, {
                expiresIn: '30m'
              }
            );

            res.json({
              success: true,
              token: 'JWT ' + token,
              role: user.role
            });
          } else {
            console.log("Log err")
            res.status(404).json({
              message: 'Login failed!'
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }).catch(function (error) {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: 'There was an error!'
      });
    })
  }
}


module.exports = AuthController;
```

Here's a log of the response.

> POST /api/authenticate 404 5.092 ms - 47
>
> Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `username`, `password`, `role`,
>   `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `users` AS `user` WHERE
>   `user`.`username` = 'sipho' LIMIT 1;
>
> POST /api/authenticate 200 519.020 ms - 193

I have tried everything. Please help because I am very new to node and Express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express responde automatically 404 when the path doesn't match with anyone declare. But in your case, I think is declared right.
As far as you are returning 404 code in several places, the way I'd check the error would be this:

- Make sure with logs that the execution is entering in your method
- Write different logs / console to know which 404 is being returned. Or you can return different http codes in every place in order to find which one is failing
- After that you have to check why is entering in that condition and try to find the origin of the error.

For example. If the 404 returned is the first one, could be because in the ajax part you are not sending username or password. If it is second one, maybe because the username is not in registered or saved in your database.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much : ). Apparently it was returning 404 errors and not the message object as was expected. I had to sprinkle `console.log` statements everywhere and managed to trace the root of the problem. Thank you very much for the advice